# sorting strings based on your own values in python

Tags: python, string, list

I think this may be a rather simple question but I've searched other questions and haven't really found anything completely relevant.

Say I have a list containing a number of strings like

mylist = ['queen', 'jack', 'queen', 'king', 'jack']

Now, I want to sort the strings in this list based on their relative values.  So let's say king = 3, queen = 2, jack = 1.

What is the simplest way to associate those values with the strings in the list and sort them accordingly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a key lookup:

```
suits = {'queen': 2, 'jack': 1, 'king': 2}
l = ['queen','jack','king']
print sorted(l, key=suits.get)
```

Comment: @samplebias: Nooooo you beat me to it!

Comment: can you explain this notation? key=lambda x: suits[x], what is x?

Comment: `x` is the argument to the anonymous function created by the `lambda` statement, see http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms

Comment: @phooji sorry about that. this is crazy sometimes, huh? the flood of answers on some of these basic questions feels like a [herd of dolphins diving into a bait ball](http://vimeo.com/4251219)  @andrew's right on the money, lambda is an anon function.

Comment: Can be written without clunky `lambda`: `sorted(l, key=suits.get)`.

Comment: Yep, lambda unnecessary here, i updated it. I use them to create keys in other contexts; guess i knee-jerked to what i'm used to.

Comment: @samplebias: Yes. Just like dolphins :-p